# retrieve selected value from multiple spinners in a arraylist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist, android-spinner

I am developing an e-commerce android application using Firebase real-time database and i am using spinners to show my products category wise in multiple spinners. What i want is when user selects something from first spinner and press add button then that value comes in an array-list named current_products and then user selects something or not from rest of spinners and these values should keep coming to current_products(array-list). I have add button for every spinner so when user press add button for a specific spinner it should get the selected product from that spinner and add into current_products. I am trying to do the same thing the problem i am facing is when a user selects something from a spinner and presses add button the value gets added in current_products but when again user open that spinner and select a different product then this product is also added in current_products instead of removing the previous product from that spinner and adding the newly selected product.
[Here is look of my database for further understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3FY9.png)

here is my code:

```
private Spinner scarfs_spinner, buttons_spinner, pins_spinner, laces_spinner;
private Button addScarfBtn, addButtonBtn, addPinsBtn, addLacesBtn;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
private ArrayList<String> scarfsList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> buttonsList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> lacesList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> pinsList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Products> all_products = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> current_products = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_customization);

    scarfs_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.scarfs_spinner);
    buttons_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.buttons_spinner);
    pins_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.pins_spinner);
    laces_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.laces_spinner);
    addScarfBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addScarfBtn);
    addButtonBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButtonsBtn);
    addPinsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addPinsBtn);
    addLacesBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addLacesBtn);
    showDataSpinner();
}

private void showDataSpinner()
{
    databaseReference.child("Products").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            for(DataSnapshot item : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (item.child("category").getValue(String.class).equals("Scarfs"))
                {
                    scarfsList.add(item.child("pname").getValue(String.class));
                }
                if (item.child("category").getValue(String.class).equals("Buttons"))
                {
                    buttonsList.add(item.child("pname").getValue(String.class));
                }
                if (item.child("category").getValue(String.class).equals("Pins"))
                {
                    pinsList.add(item.child("pname").getValue(String.class));
                }
                if (item.child("category").getValue(String.class).equals("Laces"))
                {
                    lacesList.add(item.child("pname").getValue(String.class));
                }
                all_products.add(item.getValue(Products.class));
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(CustomizationActivity.this, R.layout.style_spinner, scarfsList);
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(CustomizationActivity.this, R.layout.style_spinner, buttonsList);
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(CustomizationActivity.this, R.layout.style_spinner, pinsList);
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<>(CustomizationActivity.this, R.layout.style_spinner, lacesList);
            scarfs_spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            buttons_spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);
            pins_spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
            laces_spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter3);
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    addScarfBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            current_products.add(scarfs_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }
    });

    addButtonBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            current_products.add(buttons_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }
    });

    addPinsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            current_products.add(pins_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }
    });

    addLacesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            current_products.add(laces_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: sir, for this scenario you need the hashmap list. because it stores the data in (Key, Value) pairs. suppose you add the from scarf spinner then set you key sarch and value which is selected item from the spinner. same it goes to other spinners just change the key name as per your need. and suppose if user want to change the scarf spinner item , first you just check the scarf key of hashmap item is existed or not. if existed then replace teh value with the again selected item.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the item to a particular array position and before adding an item from the spinner, check if that position in the database is empty then populate it else clear the position content before adding (replacing) the new item.